# How to sign commits in SVN?

Tags: svn, commit, sign, pgp

In GIT we can sign commits using the `-S` flag. ([Here](http://mikegerwitz.com/papers/git-horror-story)'s some reading on why on earth you would want to do that.)

Is it possible to sign commits in SVN as well?

Comment: Subversion does not have this functionality.

Comment: Since the commits are not signed, someone with special access (i.e. admin) to the central repository can change my commits and make it look like it was me. However, can another client also change my commits without this being logged, that is, can this peer of mine mess up a commit I made and blame it on me? Note that I'm using SVN+SSH. [ Should this go to security? ]

Comment: commits are immutable unless you have direct filesystem access *and* can take the repository offline *and* fudge the commit checksum while you're changing the commit itself. And since each revision is built upon the previous one, you'd probably break future revs too. IOW, it *may* be possible, but there's no way you could do it without someone noticing.

Comment: Changing the name associated with a commit is possible from a client if you have the appropriate hook script installed, but that requires the administrator set it up.